# Склонение имени при назывании по имени-отчеству

Tags: разговорная-речь

Часто в ***разговорной речи*** не склоняют имя человека при упоминании его в 3-м лице по имени-отчеству.

> Я сказал об этом Виктор Иванычу.
>
> Попросите, пожалуйста, Василь Василича.
>
> Ты не видел Алексан Тимофеича?

Так вот, вопрос: это действительно допустимо в разговорной речи и можно, не смущаясь, так говорить?

Comment: Раз люди говорят, то, видать, допустимо.  Насчёт смущения, конечно, рекомендаций нет.  Смущайтесь, если считаете нужным.

Comment: Считать нужным смущаться — глупее не придумаешь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В разговорной речи такое ужатие имён и отчеств не только допусимо, но... бонтонно.

Привезли начинающую поэтессу к Ахматовой, она робела ужасти как и ляпнула: "Здрасти, Анна АндрЕЕвна". Потом сокрушалась...

Анна Андревна, Сан Саныч, Лиль Николавна, Галин Васильна, Пал Палыч ("Антон Палыч Чехов однажды заметил...") — норма литературная.

Все звуки имени и отчества проговариваются только с официальной трибуны — норма официозная.

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В разговорной речи это допустимо. Сам говорю "Андрей Георгича или Пётр Евгенича", например. Ничто не может заставить людей произносить имя-отчество согласно написанию или склонять имя в 3-м лице (ничто, кроме чинопочитания или страха перед "большим начальником").

Comment: Очень убедительно!

Comment: *Ничто не может заставить людей правильно...* Вопрос, что считать правильным... Имеется ведь в виду согласно написанию, побуквенно? Может, так и перепишете? А то я перечитывал сейчас и долго врубиться не мог в смысл. (Как в 15-м году понял, уже не помню. :))

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл хорошую [статейку](http://studfile.net/preview/4259560/page:5) по теме собственного вопроса. Процитирую её частично:

> Дело в том, что исторически нормы произношения русских имен-отчеств исходят из традиций сценической речи, которая, в свою очередь, опирается на старомосковское произношение. Русская сцена и сегодня не приемлет строго побуквенного произношения при обращении по имени и отчеству. Отчества, мужские и женские, произносятся со стяжением (пропуском) срединных слогов (конечно, в соединении со сценической дикцией):
>
> *Васи[л’и]ч, Игна[т’и]ч, Никола[и]ч, Яков[л’и]ч или Я[л’и]ч (Васильевич, Игнатьевич, Николаевич, Яковлевич);*
>
> *Анд[р’э]вна, Алек[с’э]вна, Васи[л’нн]а, Ива[нн]а, Фёд[ънн]а (Андреевна, Алексеевна, Васильевна, Ивановна, Федоровна).*
>
> Стяжение наблюдается и при произнесении слитного имени-отчества, в том числе при склонении. При этом произношение имени характеризуется стяженным окончанием и даже начальным стяженным слогом:
>
> *Ма[р’] Ва[нн]а, Алекса[н] Анд[р’э]вна, к Катери[н] Яко[л’н’]е;*
>
> *Па[л] Па[лы]ч, Миха[лы]ва[ны]ч; от **Игорь Никола[и]ча.***

Как видно, выделенный мною жирным последний пример как раз соответствует первому примеру моего вопроса (при общем косвенном падеже имя в именительном). Приятно найти подтверждение того, что так правильно говорить. ;)

Интересна также именная часть "Катерин" в дательном падеже без окончания *-е.*